# How to turn multiple array values into text in HTML?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am quite new to JavaScript and am trying to create a tool that will check for certain words within given text. Right now I am testing and can have the results logged in the console but am having trouble getting all of the results to display using innerText. Basically, I'm wanting it to show which of the given words exist within the string, but it will only show one of the results.

Here is my JS code:

```
const wordCheckOutput = document.getElementById("word-check-output");

let wordsToCheckFor = ['the', 'a', 'ensure', 'when'];

let sampleString = 'This is a sample string to ensure the code is working.'

function wordCheck() {

    let i = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < wordsToCheckFor.length; i++) {
       for (let j = 0; j < sampleString.split(' ')[j]; j++)
       if (wordsToCheckFor[i] === sampleString.split(' ')[j] {
          let results = wordsToCheckFor[i];
          console.log(results);
          wordCheckOutput.innerText = results;
    }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly certain I have to change the results with the [i], but everything I've tried hasn't worked and I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: first of all, your `j` variable is declared multiple times. Fix this and move on

Comment: PS... `wordCheckOutput.innerText = results` is not the same as `wordCheckOutput.innerText += results`. With every `wordCheckOutput.innerText` you're clearing the previous content. Also use rather `textContent` instead of `innerText`

Comment: Maybe the JIT compiler of the JS engine is smart enough to hoist the common subexpression out of the loop, but you are splitting sampleString on spaces over and over and over again.

Comment: `split()` returns an `array` of strings. What do you expect `j < sampleString.split(' ')[j]` to check for?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably rather use `.textContent` than `.innerHTML`, unless you really want to create a proper HTML markup text. Here is a simpler version with `Array.filter()` and `Array.includes()` that will get you the desired result:

```js
const wordCheckOutput = document.getElementById("word-check-output"),
      wordsToCheckFor = ['the', 'a', 'ensure', 'when'],
      sampleString = 'This is a sample string to ensure the code is working.';
      
wordCheckOutput.innerText = sampleString.split(" ").filter(w=>wordsToCheckFor.includes(w)).join(", ")
```

```html
<h3>The following words occur in the sentence</h3>
<div id="word-check-output"></div>
```

In case you want to do that with `for` loops then this should work:

```js
const wordCheckOutput = document.getElementById("word-check-output"),
  wordsToCheckFor = ['the', 'a', 'ensure', 'when'],
  sampleString = 'This is a sample string to ensure the code is working.',
  results = [];

for (let arr = sampleString.split(' '), i = 0; i < wordsToCheckFor.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
    if (wordsToCheckFor[i] === arr[j]) 
      results.push(wordsToCheckFor[i]);
}

wordCheckOutput.innerText = results.join(", ")
```

```html
<h3>The following words occur in the sentence</h3>
<div id="word-check-output"></div>
```

Please note, that I split the text array *only once*, before I go into the `for` loop. I also do the assignment to the `.innerText` property of the results div outside the loop. Assigning new text to `.ìnnerHTML`, `.ìnnerText` or `.textContent` properties of a DOM elements will slow down the overall page rendering process and should therefore not be done repeatedly in a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining your changes in a way that’s easy to understand! I realized it was taking too long and would timeout when the sample text was too much, so splitting the array before the loop makes so much sense and I wouldn’t have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let wordsToCheckFor = ['the', 'a', 'ensure', 'when'];
let sampleString = 'This is a sample string to ensure the code is working.';

wordsToCheckFor.forEach(function(wordToCheck){
  if(sampleString.includes(wordToCheck)){
    console.log(wordToCheck + " was found.")
  }
})
```

Comment: `sampleString = 'thereafter';` "the was found." "a was found."

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with word boundaries `\b` and pipe delimited `|` match options of the desired words to match:

```js
const arr = ["the", "a", "ensure", "when"];
const str = "This is a sample string to ensure the code is working.";


const res = str.match(new RegExp(`\\b(${arr.join("|")})\\b`, `ig`))
document.querySelector("#word-check-output").textContent = res.join(", ");
```

```html
<div id="word-check-output"></div>
```